# How can I implement existing Infopath template into a new list on the same SharePoint site

Tags: infopath, template

Want to create a new list that will include part of the items that i have from existing Infopath template (exist on other list). Is there a way to upload/copy and than edit it as I want to use for the new list?
Thanks 
Almog

Comment: Save the list as a template and keep the content. Download the template/stp file and upload and create the new list with that.

Comment: @Christoffer, you should post it as answer.

Comment: One add on you might need to rewire any lookup fields (if you have any) after you create a list from template.

Answer (score 0):

Save the list as a template in SharePoint, then create the new list from that template.  after that edit it's content, but starting with all the fields, rules, etc that you already built in the first version of the form.